# HTML video tag suggestions

Tags: html, video, mime-types

I have strange problem, that i can't resolve. I have stream that i have to put in a site. I don't have access to the stream link which is http://94.26.60.47:8880/865tv.mpg

The codec used is mp4. I know that this is strange, but i can't change this link, and i need to put it in a site using HTML5 video tag. I used this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test Stream</title>
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="http://94.26.60.47:8880/865tv.mpg" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
 </body>
</html>
```

As a result in Chrome i just see empty player. In Mozilla i get more debug info:
*HTTP "Content-Type" of "video/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource http://94.26.60.47:8880/865tv.mpg failed.
Invalid URI. Load of media resource failed.*

What i did, is changing mime.types in my apache conf (restarted after the change) (remove mpg from video/mpeg and add it to video/mp4), and no success.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I may not help but I've got a "the connection used to fetch this resource was not secure error" on FF.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that you cannot play mpeg1 or mpeg2 using html5.  I also was looking into something like that.  You could embed a VLC web player that can handle these video formats pretty easily. Maybe consider...  https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/

```
<html>
     <title>VLC Mozilla plugin test page</title>
     <body>
          <center><embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
              width="640" height="480" id="vlc">
          </embed></center>
     <script language="Javascript">
         <!--
         var vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");
         var id = vlc.playlist.add("http://94.26.60.47:8880/865tv.mpg");
         vlc.playlist.playItem(id);
         //!-->
     </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As i said in my question clearly, it is not mpeg format, but mp4. Codec used to encode the stream is mp4a. There is michmash between file extension and the codec used. There is no a way to change this extension. Also the way you propose would not work in the modern Chrome, because they stopped these application types.

Comment: @bksi You are wrong. I downloaded and looked at the file with a hex editor. It is not an mp4 container. it is a mpeg transport stream.

Comment: When i open it in VLC media player, it shows mp4 codec in codec information.